# My program seems to be running infinitely, and I'm not sure where it is failing to continue

Tags: haskell, io, ghci

I've been working on writing to a file in Haskell using I/O, but it is just sitting there running with no end product.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  hawkID <- getLine
  let text = "module Operations where\nimport " ++ hawkID ++ "\n\nsample :: (" ++ hawkID ++ "a)\nsample = B\n\
                                                                                        \size :: (" ++ hawkID ++ " a) -> Int\nsize x = 0\n\n\
                                                                                        \depth :: (" ++ hawkID ++ " a) -> Int\ndepth x = 0\n\n\
                                                                                        \dropN :: (" ++ hawkID ++ " a) -> (" ++hawkID ++ " a)\ndropN x = x\n\n\
                                                                                        \countB :: (" ++ hawkID ++ " a) -> Int\ncountB x = 0\n\
                                                                                        \ltoB :: (" ++ hawkID ++ " a) -> (" ++ hawkID ++ " b)\nltoB x = B\n\n\
                                                                                        \toString :: (" ++ hawkID ++ " a) -> String\ntoString x = \"\"\n\n\
                                                                                        \mapHawkid :: (a -> b) -> (" ++ hawkID++ " a) -> (" ++ hawkID ++ " b)\n\n\
                                                                                        \substB :: (" ++ hawkID ++ " a) -> (" ++ hawkID ++" a) -> (" ++ hawkID ++ " a)\n\
                                                                                        \substB x y = B"
  let file =  writeFile "Desktop/hawkID.hs"  text

  return ()
```

Comment: It is simply waiting for you to enter a `hawkID` in the stdin... Enter an id and hit ENTER.

Answer (score 1):

Are you entering text and pressing enter to satisfy the `getLine` call? There will be no prompt. If you want a prompt, I think you would need a (for example) `putStr` and probably to disable output buffering.

Also, your `writeFile` call will not be evaluated - you would need to put it in the body of the `do` block like:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  putStr "Hawk ID: "
  hawkID <- getLine
  let text = ...
  writeFile "hawkID.hs" text
```

Comment: Ah I wasn't I thought it would read it like :main Biehl for example. Thank you!

Comment: @hawkeye Ah no `getLine` reads a line from stdin. For the command line arguments you would use `getArgs` from `System.Environment`. Of course I think you could pipe a line in rather than enter it directly.